# How to fix this JOIN query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM people 
JOIN pets ON people.id = pets.owner_id;
```

It returns results for people who have pets. But not all people have pets. I want the query to return all persons from the people table and IF they happen to have pets to return the pets also.

But since pets are optional, how can I make this query return even people with no pets?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use **LEFT JOIN**

```
SELECT * 
FROM people 
LEFT JOIN pets ON people.id = pets.owner_id;
```

**[JOIN Explanation](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)**

**JOIN in SQL**
[image]

Comment: Note that this visual explanation is predicated on the assumption that both set a and set b contain unique rows.

Answer (score -1):

`JOIN` default to `INNER JOIN`

in your case you should use

```
left join
```

Comment: `JOINT`? Chronic MySQL, dude.